# AWS Cognito sign in with alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to configure sign in for my AWS Cognito User Pool, but I'm unable to select anything from this screen (all the options are greyed out):

[image]

I have a free tier account, do I need to upgrade to enable this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make changes to an existing user pool? You cannot update alias settings and the set of required attributes for an existing user pool.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the attributes settings after creates the user pool